# yarn test: all tests passed but returned "error Command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, yarnpkg

I used to use npm but recently switched to yarn. When I run `yarn test` it shows all tests passed but below says `error Command failed with exit code 1` with no other information on what could have caused this error

node version: 6.3.1

yarn version: 0.16.3

potential cause
`console.error node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:117
    Unhandled promise rejection Error: Actions may not be an undefined.
        at dispatch (/node_modules/redux-mock-store/lib/index.js:35:19)
        at /node_modules/redux-thunk/lib/index.js:14:16
        at dispatch (/node_modules/redux/lib/applyMiddleware.js:45:18)
        at /src/actions/ontologies.js:159:7
        at run (/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:87:22)
        at /node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:100:28
        at flush (/node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18:9)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)`

Comment: Have you tried updating to Yarn v0.18.0 if possible? There may have been some improvements in error reporting since 0.16.3.

Comment: yes I did but nothing changed

Comment: Could you post the whole output just in case you've missed something?

Comment: edited original post to show the only thing in output that wasn't a green checkmark

Comment: Looks like you should check `/src/actions/ontologies.js:159:7` for an undefined action.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it's caused by `snapshots obsolete` after some test code changes. So the solution is to delete those test data in the `__snapshots__` folder

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

the error code was due to line coverage being below the value that I defined (90%). It already told me `line coverage 86.8% is below user defined value of 90%` so I thought it unlikely that yarn would "double report" that error.

Comment: This is very interesting as I'm having a similar issue, except for that I removed all `coverage` settings. When running through `gulp-jest`, it actually complains names coverage threshold breaches as the reason. Any idea?

Comment: What is line coverage?

Comment: @NamanJain The percentage of code lines that are covered with tests

Answer (score 0):

Did you use forEach + async/await in your tests?

I have resolved this issue, use for await...of instead forEach

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Jianwu Chen pointed out, this was also my issue.
I resolved it by running `yarn test -u` or `npm run test -- -u`.

`-u` will update the snapshots in order to delete the obsolete entries.

Comment: what does -u option do?

Comment: It will update the snapshots, so the warning wouldn't rise again. I'll add it to my comment.