# Jest failing "due to coverage threshold breaches" w/o coverage settings

Tags: jestjs

After upgrading several packages in my `devDependencies`, my Jest tests are failing due to threshold breaches, while there is no `coverage` settings.

If I run `gulp-jest`, they are failing with

```
Error in plugin "gulp-jest"
Message:
    Tests Failed due to coverage threshold breaches
```

Running `yarn run jest`, the error is just

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The latter seems to be in line with [yarn test: all tests passed but returned "error Command failed with exit code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980837/yarn-test-all-tests-passed-but-returned-error-command-failed-with-exit-code-1), where also coverage thresholds were the reason.

The weird thing is that my thresholds were already set to 0. Now I've removed all `coverage` settings from my `gulpfile`, it's still failing.

In `package.json` I cannot find any other settings. Am I missing a location?

My versions are

- node LTS 10.16.3
- jest 22.4.4
- gulp-jest 4.0.3

Comment: I just tried in another package of my monorepo, and I'm noticing that the `testMatch` setting is also not what is set in `gulpfile`.

Comment: The help center defines that "programming questions" are also about development tools. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: I found that my `package.json` had a useless `config` key in config object. While this changed jest's behaviour in most packages, I'm still having one package that still fails due to threshold breaches.

Comment: Would the downvoters mind explaining their issue with my question? I want to follow the guidelines, and read them, but can't figure out what's wrong. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the test that failed due to threshold breaches (even though no thresholds were defined) we were able to fix it by deleting the snapshot file `*.test.js.snap`.

It's weird, and the error message is quite misleading.

Additionally, we had an extra `config` key in our config objects for `gulp-jest`:

`jest({config: {…}}`

This seems to have been dropped in some version.